# Trouble with iterator parameter in template method

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector, unique-ptr

I am trying to write a method to transfer a unique_ptr from one std::vector to another.

```
template<typename T>
void transferOne(vector<std::unique_ptr<T> > &to, 
                 vector<std::unique_ptr<T> >::iterator what, 
                 vector<std::unique_ptr<T> > &from) {
    to.push_back(std::move(*what));
    from.erase(what);
}
```

Clang gives me an error: 
missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'vector >::iterator'

Any ideas how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Clang* tells you, put *typename* in front of the iterator type:

```
template<typename T>
void transferOne(vector<std::unique_ptr<T> > &to, 
                 typename vector<std::unique_ptr<T> >::iterator what, 
                 vector<std::unique_ptr<T> > &from) {
    to.push_back(std::move(*what));
    from.erase(what);
}
```

The keyword `typename` is used to tell the compiler, that `vector<std::unique_ptr<T> >::iterator` is a type. Without instantiating the template, the compiler can't in general find that out by itself, because there might be a specialization of the template `vector`, where the member *iterator* is a static variable instead.